# Add a disabled selected option tag using Materialize forms with Angular2 and firebase

Tags: angular, forms, firebase, materialize

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu using materialize-css in Angular2. This dropdown menu is subject to expansion as users add more options to the menu, and consequently the items in the menu are stored in a database. In this case, the database is firebase.

I can get the menu to populate with values from the database using the `*ngFor` directive, but only when I don't leave in a disabled and selected option tag at the top.

In other words the following code implements the firebase stuff correctly:

```
  <div class="input-field col m3 s12">
    <select formControlName="positiveControl3Bound" materialize="material_select" id="posCntrl3">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of retrievedDbOpts">{{opt.$value}}</option>
    </select>
    <label for="posCntrl3">This one from firebase works b/c there's no disabled selected option:</label>
  </div>
```

But, it's not as user-friendly as the `<option disabled selected>Choose from the options</option>` line in the code below (which doesn't successfully implement the firebase list):

```
<div class="input-field col m3 s12">
    <select formControlName="useCase" materialize="material_select" id="useCase">
      <option disabled selected>Choose from the options</option>
      <option *ngFor="let opt of retrievedDbOpts">{{opt.$value}}</option>
    </select>
    <label for="useCase">But this one from firebase doesn't work:</label>
  </div>
```

I have a reproducible example here:

```
git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/materializeAngularFormSO.git
cd materializeAngularFormSO
npm install
ng serve
```

Then, open a browser and navigate to `http://localhost:4200/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed your code and saw  these results:

1. Several errors in the console:

```
    ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'positiveControl1Bound'
    ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'positiveControl2Bound'
    ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'positiveControl3Bound'
    ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'useCase'
```

2. The items from the database are not appended to the last select control of your form

I modified your `ngOnInit` to declare the form controls mentioned in the error messages:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      positiveControl1Bound: '',        // Added this line
      positiveControl2Bound: '',        // Added this line
      positiveControl3Bound: '',        // Added this line
      useCase: '',                      // Added this line
    });

    this.db.getOpts().subscribe(opts=>{
      this.retrievedDbOpts = opts;
    });
  }
```

Executing the application after that change, I see no errors in the console, and the last select element now shows the items from the database in addition to the disabled first option.

---

**Update**: there was another problem when your tried to add an empty disabled option as the first item, and fill the options with items from the database. If the disabled option was selected, the other options did not show up; and if the disabled option was not selected, it was not displayed by default.

It appears that getting the options from the database first, and then making the first option disabled, allows to have the first option selected and the other options present in the list. Also, the first option should not be selected before getting the other options, so I had to remove that attribute and give the option a dummy value (e.g. `value="(choose)"`). Here is the code for the age class list:

```
<div class="input-field col m4 s12">
  <select formControlName="ageClassBound" materialize="material_select" id="ageClass">
    <option value="(choose)" [disabled]="disabledAgeClass" >Choose age class</option>
    <option *ngFor="let age of ageClasses">{{age.$value}}</option>
  </select>
  <label for="ageClass">Age Class</label>
</div>
```

```
disabledAgeClass: boolean = false;

this.db.getAgeClasses().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(ageClasses=>{
  this.ageClasses = ageClasses;
  this.disabledAgeClass = true;
});
```

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: I did manage to reproduce my error with a slightly more complex example at: git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu.git
git checkout SO_question
npm install
ng serve
Navigate to http://localhost:4200/createaccount

Comment: as that page loads, keep an eye on the "Age class" field on the bottom right. The disabled selected option will be there, but will quickly be replaced by other options from the database.

Comment: You found a good way to get my attention. :-)  When I try to build your project, it complains about this file that is not found in `app.module.ts`: `import { masterFirebaseConfig } from './api-keys';`.

Comment: Sorry, @ConnorsFan!
Go to https://firebase.google.com/, create a project, and select 'Add Firebase to your web app'
Create a file called 'api-keys.ts' in dataJitsu/src/app/
Add
export var masterFirebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxx"
  databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
};
to api-keys.ts, replacing values with those from Firebase

Comment: Before doing that, do you see any error in the console when you reproduce your bug?

Comment: This is the console:
addScript.js:8 [Script Loader] ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.49.module.exports (addScript.js:20), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
   ...
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
log @ addScript.js:8
webpackJsonp.49.module.exports @ addScript.js:25
169 @ materialize.min.css?215f:1
...
core.es5.js:2925 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
authorization.service.ts:17 null

That top error occurs on every page, though...

Comment: Now, where should I look to see the bug? The gender list looks OK.

Comment: navigate to localhost:4200/createaccount. The "age class" field should show the disabled option briefly, and then be overwritten by options from the database.

Comment: Whoops. I had said that the age class field was bottom right earlier. I meant middle right.

Comment: I get several errors like this in the console: `ERROR Error: permission_denied at /ageClasses: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162634/discussion-between-atticus29-and-connorsfan).